# Cellphone in Thailand

Tags: cellphones, thailand

I am moving to Chiang Mai, Thailand and want to activate my phone in Thailand.
I have a brand new unlocked Samsung Galaxy S Duos GSM phone. This phone has never been activated. I have noticed that SIM cards have expiration dates.

How much is the average activation cost?
How much is normal air time on cards?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "activation" cost in Thailand, just buy a sim, insert and call.

SIMs are dirt cheap, usually 50 baht, with 50 baht in call time credit, so basically free.  Calls are anywhere from 50 satang to 1 baht a minute domestically, 1 to 10 baht a minute internationally.  There are a myriad of plans offered with prepay rates.

All three cellphone companies have good coverage in Chiang Mai, AIS, DTAC and True.  AIS has the best rural coverage, True has the best international calling plans.  All three offer prepaid data packages.

All three companies have info on their websites on rates and packages in English (though sometimes you to keep selecting EN at the top as the sites don't always remember your preference from page to page).